# How should one document permission of contributors to change the licence of a project?

Tags: licensing

I'm using a Python library which is currently under GPL3. The maintainer has decided that he would like to change the licence to one which does not contaminate larger works (probably either the MIT licence or MPL2 if that makes a difference).

The question is how does he go about changing the licence? In particular, obtaining and documenting permission from the (luckily very few) contributors?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better answered by an attorney specializing in intellectual property.  An attorney's expertise is required in order to identify a suitable approach for gathering copyright holder approval of a licensing change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this done via a GitHub Issue comment thread. The author created an issue describing the intent to change the license and asked every contributor to comment if they agree to the change. This creates a public record of the approval of all contributors.

Comment: Thanks. Could you provide a GitHub link to the project that changed?

Comment: For example: https://github.com/FriendCode/gittle/issues/24

Comment: You may be able to incorporate elements of the story of the Dolphin emulator and their license change with a massive number of contributors: https://dolphin-emu.org/blog/2015/05/25/relicensing-dolphin/